# jquery: slide-in and slide-out of a box whenn scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, slide

With this code the #slidebox is sliding in from the right, after the page is scrolled down 50px. What do I have to add, when the box should slide out after 150px scrolling? Lines with "<150" conditions did't work for me... Thank you!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function(){

    if  ($(window).scrollTop() > 50)
        $('#slidebox').animate({'right':'0px'},300);

    else
        $('#slidebox').stop(true).animate({'right':'-430px'},100);

        });
    });
</script>
```

UPDATE:
This is the working result:

```
$(function() {
$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
        $('#slidebox').animate({'right': '0px'}, 300);
    }
    else
        $('#slidebox').stop(true).animate({'right':'-430px'},100);

    if($(window).scrollTop() > 500) {
        $('#slidebox').stop(true).animate({'right':'-430px'},100);
    }
});
```

Comment: the condition should be : if($(window).scrollTop() > 150)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try like that:

```
$(function() {
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            if($(window).scrollTop() > 50) {
                $('#slidebox').animate({'right': '0px'}, 300);
            }
            if($(window).scrollTop() > 150) {
                $('#slidebox').stop(true).animate({'right':'-430px'},100);
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! this was quite Close. The only problem was, that the box did not slide out when scrolling up. so I had to add   else
            $('#slidebox').stop(true).animate({'right':'-430px'},100); after the first if. Now, everything is fine. Thank you!